# How to insert characters in between in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have this data from the database `12345123412` but in my page I need to display it as `12345-1234-12`. Any ideas on how to handle this? I'm trying to do the `.split()`

Comment: Is it always in the pattern of 5 digits- 4digits-2 digits?

Comment: @Varun Yes it will always be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the string is always going to be formatted the exact same way, there's no reason to use jQuery for this:

```
var str = '12345123412';

var formatted = str.slice(0, 5) + '-' + str.slice(5, 9) + '-' + str.slice(9);
  //=> 12345-1234-12
```

Answer (score 1):

There so many ways to do this but you can use a simple function to convert a number to a dass separated number as follows.

```
 //This function returns the result as per your question.
 function commaSeparateNumber(val){   
    var regex =new  RegExp("(\\d{5})(\\d+)");
    var valEdit = val.toString().replace(regex, '$1'+'-');
    var valleft = val.toString().replace(regex, '$2');
    var regex =new  RegExp("(\\d{4})(\\d+)");
    val = valleft.toString().replace(regex, '$1'+'-'+'$2');    
    return valEdit+val;
 }
 console.log(commaSeparateNumber(12345123412));

//This function work for change at every 4 digit insertion
function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d{4})(\d+)/.test(val.toString())){
      val = val.toString().replace(/(\d{4})(\d+)/, '$1'+'-'+'$2');
    }
    return val;
  }
  console.log(commaSeparateNumber(12345123412));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplified approach...with jquery..

Get 3 substrings then format..

```
Var id = 12345123412
Function getId(id){     
    Var sub1 =id.substring(0,5);
    Var sub2 =id.substring(5,9);
    Var sub3 =id.substring(9,11);
    Var id = sub1 +"-"+sub2+"-"+sub3;
    Return id;
}

getId();
```